# Jenkins running protractor test

Tags: selenium, jenkins, protractor, selenium-grid

I'm trying to launch my protractor test with selenium and protractor.
To do that on my pc I start on console 1 a selenium server:

```
webdriver-manager update
webdriver-manager start
```

Then on console 2 I launch tests:

```
protractor test.config.js
```

I would like to do the same in Jenkins. The problem is that after starting selenium I cannot do anything because the console is locked with selenium server running. So what I need is to launch the selenium server in background (in parallel) to other processes. Am I right? Maybe there is a Jenkins plugin to achieve that?

=== EDIT

Thanks for your responses. Finally I decided not to use the headless browser but to use selenium-plugin to run test on remote machines. However I have found other problems to configure my test environment. What I achieved till now is establishing connection between selenium hub and nodes. When I'm executing my protractor.config.js file I have the following error :

```
E/launcher - Error: Error: Could not find chromedriver
```

What I don't understand is how to set the path of the driver? And which driver should it be, the one from hub or the one from host. In the selenium-plugin config page there is an input to set a `Chromedriver path` but it's not taken into account. I also tried to set the `chromeDriver` param in `protractor.conf.js` file, but I still recieve the same error. Here is my `protractor.config.js`:

```
exports.config = {

    directConnect: true,

    // path to driver on node server
    chromeDriver: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/selenium-standalone/.selenium/chromedriver/2.21-x64-chromedriver',
    // path to driver on hub server
    // chromeDriver: '/u01/apps/jenkins/data/tools/jenkins.plugins.nodejs.tools.NodeJSInstallation/NodeJS_5.12.0/lib/node_modules/selenium-standalone/.selenium/chromedriver/2.21-x64-chromedriver',

    // Capabilities to be passed to the webdriver instance.
    capabilities: {
        'browserName': 'chrome',
        shardTestFiles: true,
        maxInstances: 3
    },

    ...
};
```

Comment: You have a few choices. Did you want to run the tests headless which is what will happen if you add the selenium server step to the Jenkins build process (on windows this runs in session zero and can cause some elements to not be visible because the screen size is limited). I previously used grunt and the grunt plugin grunt-shell-spawn to run the selenium server asynchronously but this will be in headless mode. If you have a selenium server hub and node open on your desktop Jenkins will route the tests to that and run them visibly on your desktop in the browser. I can provide samples for both.

Comment: I was in the same boat as you a few months back and applied the same solution as you did, using the Selenium Grid plugin. I was not able to set the path to Chrome driver in conf. file. But as a workaround, if you add chromdriver's path in your path environment variable, it works for both local and remote. What I mean is whichever local/remote machine is giving this problem, set path variable in that machine itself, no need to set it from Jenkins or your tests. P.S. Sorry to add this an answer but don't have privileges to add comments.

Answer (score 0):

**Two** quick work arounds and **One** ideal case i could think of:

**work-around1:** would be to run the `webdriver manager` in a separate `bat` file and call it in your batch script (Windows environment)

**server.bat**

```
webdriver-manager update
webdriver-manager start
```

**batch script**

```
call "path to your server.bat"
========Server Started========
protractor "path to you protractor config file" // if protractor is installed globally else change directory to specific folder where it is installed & execute the same command
```

**work-around2:** would be to get rid of `webdriver-manager` and use `directConnect= true` in your `config` file which would directly interact with firefox & chrome browsers if set.

Noe: There is an overhead for chrome browser. you need to do `webdriver-manager update` for downloading the chrome driver or manually put it in the specific location.

**Ideal Case** It is a good practice to separate our testing environment with that of `selenium server` which is always running. There are two good providers- `Saucelabs` & `BrowserStack` you can choose either of them based on your needs.
I hope this would give you some understanding!

Answer (score 0):

This is how we have done it:

Under build, add a "Execute Shell" step and do something similar:

```
cd $WORKSPACE/ && npm update && npm install
$WORKSPACE/node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager update --standalone
$WORKSPACE/node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager status
grunt run-e2e-tests:<PASS NECESSARY PARAMETERS>
```

This will be then executed on the Jenkins slave running the job.

Hope it helps. :)